# Eclipse RCP Export Product Encounters a Problem

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a complex Eclipse Rich Client Platform GUI with 4 Eclipse plug-ins that I developed.  I'm constructing it on Eclipse 3.5.2, Build id: M20100211-1343

It works just fine when I run it from inside of Eclipse as an Eclipse Application.

When I try to export the Eclipse Product using the export wizard on the Overview panel of the product file, I get this error:

```
'Export Product' has encountered a problem.

C:\BOPEclipse3.5RabId\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:100: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\BOPEclipse3.5RabId\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:345:
C:\BOPEclipse3.5RabId\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\assemblyLocation\tmp\gui\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715 not found.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\BOPEclipse3.5RabId\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:345:
C:\BOPEclipse3.5RabId\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\assemblyLocation\tmp\gui\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715 not found.
```

I looked at the directory location given in the error.  The equinox launcher plug-in is there.

The version 1.0.201.R35x_v20090715 matches the version in the error message.

I have the equinox launcher plug-in, and the win32.win32.x86 platform fragment in the Dependencies list of the product file.

I have the "The product includes native launcher artifacts" check box in the Overview panel of the product file checked.

I have org.eclipse.equinox.launcher in the list of Required Plug-ins in the Dependencies panel of the GUI plug-in XML.

I added "javacDefaultEncoding.. = UTF-8" to the first line of the build.properties file of the GUI plug-in.  (I found this advice on a Japanese blog.)

I have cleaned the plug-in projects multiple times.

Edited to add what I tried today:

I created a new Eclipse 3.5 instance.  Didn't help.

I copied the workspace and tried to use Eclipse 3.6.  Same error, different line numbers.

I created a Hello World RCP and tried to package it on Eclipse 3.5.  Same error.  I used a different workspace.  Same error.

I created the same Hello World RCP and tried to package it on Eclipse 3.6.  Same error.

End of today's edits.

I've searched eclipse.org and the Internet.

I'm hoping that one of you has encountered this problem before, and can point me to a solution.  If I ever figure out how to solve this problem, I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution.

I can package the Hello World RCP if I set the JRE System Library to Java 1.5.  I get the error when I set the JRE System Library to Java 1.6.

It's going to take a couple of days to convert my real RCP application to Java 1.5.  I hope this solves the problem.

I've reported this problem to the Eclipse Foundation.  It's bug number [337,235](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337235).